# Perl Moose Dynamic assign the value to attribute suggestion

Tags: perl, moose, moosex-types

I am trying to accomplish the following.

- I have a Moose style modules A and B
- A need metadata as mandatory params
- B wants to create the object of A multiple time
- hence wanted to set as an attribute

Is there a better way to do this (so that I can pass the metadata to package A and in package B avoid calling new multiple times) also trying to get it done 1 liner if possible.

```perl
package A {

    use Moose;
    has 'metadata' => (
        is      => 'rw',
        isa     => 'HashRef',
        default => sub {{}},
        required => 1
    );

    sub process {
        die unless keys %{shift->metadata};
        # ... process
        print "Success!\n";
    }

    __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

}
#######B#########
package B {
    use Moose;
    use A;

    has 'obj_a' => (
        is      => 'rw',
        isa     => 'A',
        writer  => 'set_meta',
    );

    sub _set_meta {
        my ( $self, $metadata) = @_;
        return $self->set_meta(A->new(metadata => $metadata));
    }

    sub obj_with_meta {
        my ( $self, $metadata) = @_;
        return A->new(metadata => $metadata);
    }

    __PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

    1;
}

############
use B;
my $b = B->new();

# want to call like this but I am sure I am missing something which moose is providing
# here I am supposed to call obj_a instead of _set_meta I believe
#calling _set_meta I am bypassing the Moose attribute I guess
$b->_set_meta({id=>'id for metadata'})->process;

#works
$b->obj_with_meta({id=>'id for metadata'})->process;
```

Note above code is working
output is
Success!
Success!

I am trying to know if there is anything in moose that I can leverage. so that I can share data to the next class by writing to meta may be or using some trait maybe.

package A is the catalyst controller
package B is an independent module not tightly coupled with the catalyst.

Comment: Both the calls work. What's the problem?

Comment: @choroba B::_set_meta returns a B instance which does not implement process(). Looks like a delegate pattern would be a solution.

Comment: @clamp: Why doesn't it die then?

Comment: I am trying to know if there is anything in moose that I can leverage. so that I can share data to next class by writing to meta may be or using some trait may be

Comment: description updated

Comment: @choroba sorry, wrong assumption about the generated writer. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You're saying A is a Catalyst controller. Why does your Catalyst-independent package B instantiate new controllers? That is... unusual. An attribute on a Catalyst controller can be passed in via Catalyst config (as in the config file, or with `__PACKAGE__->config(...)` in the package itself , and instances of these controllers typically stick around for a while. Can you explain explain in more detail what you are actually trying to do please? Try to be a little less generic. Give them better names, and tell us what they are for please.

Comment: @simbabque 
lets say A => Controller::User  GET|POST => localhost/user controller only takes request and validate.
B => API::User (uses DBI plain SQL query to perform the operation) where I can create object and do db operations. for db operation, session data need to pass to API::User.

Reason for keeping B separate is this way I can even switch the framework in future.
suppose to mojo or dancer as per the need.
request received by Controller::User and want to insert to hence 
API::User->new('metadata' => $c->session->data)->insert;
everytime I will need something like above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separating business logic from your controllers in a Catalyst app is a great idea. You can encapsulate it into its own modules and use them via a thin Catalyst::Model layer.

You don't actually need to worry about passing the session in from the controller, because all Catalyst::Components provide you with a means to do this, called [`ACCEPT_CONTEXT`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Component#ACCEPT_CONTEXT($c,-@args)). This is a method that you can implement in any component, but typically it's used in models. It is called whenever a `$c->model(...)` call is done, and it gets passed the context object `$c`, and is supposed to return an object that can be used like a model. This might or might not be a Catalyst::Component object.

I've build a sample application that I will be using for this answer. You can find [the full source code in this github repository](https://github.com/simbabque/stackoverflow-72096513-sample-catalyst-app).

Let's assume there is a Catalyst::Model class called MyApp::Model::API::User, with the following code. It inherits from [Catalyst::Model::DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Model::DBI) in order to leverage database handle caching via Catalyst.

```perl
package MyApp::Model::API::User;

use strict;
use warnings;

use API::User;

use parent 'Catalyst::Model::DBI';

sub ACCEPT_CONTEXT {
    my ( $self, $c, @args ) = @_;

    $c->log->debug( sprintf 'Creating a new API::User object for %s line %d',
        ( caller(2) )[ 0, 2 ] );

    return API::User->new(
        dbh      => $self->dbh,
        metadata => $c->session->{data},
    );
}

1;
```

Every time a Controller does `$c->model('API::User')` the `ACCEPT_CONTEXT` method gets called, and it instantiates a class called API::User, which is my implementation of your Catalyst-agnostic business logic. It accepts a database handle object, which the DBI Model provides for us, as well as the metadata, which we take from the user's session.

In my example I've made the user's ID part of the session so that there is actual metadata to play with (and if there is none, we create one, but that's not important here).

```perl
package API::User;

use Moose;
use DBI;

has metadata => (
    isa      => 'HashRef',
    is       => 'ro',
    required => 1,           # either it's required or it has a default
);

has dbh => (
    isa      => 'DBI::db',
    is       => 'ro',
    required => 1,
);

sub create { ... }

sub read {
    my ($self) = @_;

    my $sql = 'SELECT id, number_of_writes FROM user WHERE id=?';
    my $sth = $self->dbh->prepare($sql);

    $sth->execute( $self->metadata->{id} );

    return $sth->fetchrow_hashref;
}

sub write { ... }

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

The API::User has three methods. It can create, read and write. This is all very much simplified as an example. We will focus on reading in this answer. Note how the `metadata` property is `required`, but has no `default`. You can't have both, because they contradict each other. You want this to be passed in, so you want it to blow up if it's missing, rather than set a default value of an empty hash reference.

Finally, in a Controller this is used as follows.

```perl
package MyApp::Controller::User;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

BEGIN { extends 'Catalyst::Controller' }

__PACKAGE__->config( namespace => 'user' );

sub auto : Private {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    unless ( $c->session->{data}->{id} ) {
        # we have to initialise data first because the model depends on it
        $c->session->{data} = {}; 
        $c->session->{data}->{id} = $c->model('API::User')->create;
    }
    return 1;
}

sub index_get : Path('') Args(0) GET {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    $c->stash->{json_data} = $c->model('API::User')->read;

    return;
}

sub index_post : Path('') Args(0) POST {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    $c->stash->{json_data} = $c->model('API::User')->write;

    return;
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
```

I'm setting some session data in the `auto` action, which gets called before any other action. For a specific session this will be done once, and then that user's ID is stored in the session for subsequent requests.

In the `index_get` action I am accessing our class via `$c->model('API::User`), which will call `ACCEPT_CONTEXT` on our Model class, instantiate a new API::User object that is populated with both the existing database handle as well as the session metadata that contains our user's ID.

For the sake of the example, I'm using a JSON view so we can see what's happening in the DB.

When we curl the application to GET our user, the logs look as follows.

```
[info] *** Request 2 (0.044/s) [31642] [Fri May  6 19:01:25 2022] ***
[debug] Path is "user"
[debug] "GET" request for "user" from "127.0.0.1"
[debug] Created session "36d509c55d60c02a7a0a9cbddfae9e50b092865a"
[debug] Creating a new API::User object for MyApp::Controller::User line 15
[debug] Creating a new API::User object for MyApp::Controller::User line 23
[debug] Response Code: 200; Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8; Content-Length: unknown
[info] Request took 0.018616s (53.717/s)
.------------------------------------------------------------+-----------.
| Action                                                     | Time      |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| /user/auto                                                 | 0.013309s |
| /user/index_get                                            | 0.000640s |
| /end                                                       | 0.000994s |
|  -> MyApp::View::JSON->process                             | 0.000411s |
'------------------------------------------------------------+-----------'
```

As you can see, we go to `auto` first, and then go to `index_get`. In the debug statements above it creates two instances of API::User. One is in `auto` to create a new user because I've not supplied a session cookie, and the second is from `index_get`.

If we call it with an existing user by supplying a session cookie (see my test script in the repository) it will only call it once.

```
[info] *** Request 8 (0.037/s) [31642] [Fri May  6 19:04:16 2022] ***
[debug] Path is "user"
[debug] "GET" request for "user" from "127.0.0.1"
[debug] Found sessionid "710cb37124a7042b89f1ffa650985956949df7d0" in cookie
[debug] Restored session "710cb37124a7042b89f1ffa650985956949df7d0"
[debug] Creating a new API::User object for MyApp::Controller::User line 23
[debug] Response Code: 200; Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8; Content-Length: unknown
[info] Request took 0.017655s (56.641/s)
.------------------------------------------------------------+-----------.
| Action                                                     | Time      |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| /user/auto                                                 | 0.001887s |
| /user/index_get                                            | 0.001238s |
| /end                                                       | 0.003510s |
|  -> MyApp::View::JSON->process                             | 0.001463s |
'------------------------------------------------------------+-----------'
```

Comment: Sorry this took a while to compile, I hope it is useful to you. :)

Comment: @simplebque Sir thank you so much for all your efforts in explaining the stuff in this much detail.
I will definitely give a try and so far looks it might solve the problem I am dealing with.
once Again Tons of thanks Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @simbabque
I have created a factory method like this

```perl
package MyApp::Model::API::Factory;

use Moose::Util;
use Module::Load  qw/autoload/;

sub ACCEPT_CONTEXT {
    my ( $self, $c, $args ) = @_;

    my $module = 'MyApp::API::';

    if(!defined $args->{api_module}) {
        #eg. MyApp::Controller::API::Event::ConferenceCall::Role
        my $caller_package = ( caller(2) )[ 0 ];

        if($caller_package->can('api_module')) {
            #get from attributes
            $module .= $caller_package->new->api_module;
        } else {
            #auto detect/infer from caller name
            $caller_package =~ /MyApp::Controller::API::(.*)/;
            $module .= $1;
        }

    } else {
        #append the prefix to the module name MyApp::API::
        $module .= $args->{api_module};
    }

    $c->log->debug( sprintf "Creating a new %s object for %s line %d",$module,( caller(2) )[ 0, 2 ] );

    my $object;

    try {
        autoload  $module;
        my $meta_method;
        #auto_detect meta_method if not defined
        # here check the attributes of the class and see if it has a meta_method with suffix _metadata
        # if it does, use that
        if(!exists $args->{meta_method}) {
            my $meta = Moose::Util::find_meta($module);
            my @has    = $meta->get_attribute_list;
            foreach my $has (@has) {
                #since we have standard suffixes for the meta_methods _metadata
                if($has =~ /_metadata$/ ) {
                    $meta_method = $has;
                    last;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $meta_method = $args->{meta_method};
        }
        $object = $module->new( $meta_method => $c->{stash}{internal});
        $c->log->debug("object created by api factory for ". ref($object) . " meta attr set: $meta_method");
    } catch {
        $c->log->error( $_ );
        return;
    };

    return $object;
}

1;
```

In every controller

```perl
    my $user_api_obj = $c->model('API::Factory');

    my $result = $user_api_obj->register_user($valid_params);
```